# how show post date for specific post?

Tags: posts, date, single

i want to show specific post date into my theme not in single.php
for example i want to show published date into this :

```
<ul id="post"> <a href="https://www.example.com/ps" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="textadsa1"> <b>example text</b><br>DATE<span class="textadsa2"><img src="IMAGE URL"></span> </a>
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the post ID for the specific post/type it's easy enough yes, simply call [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) with a specific ID.

Adjust 1 to the appropriate value.

```
<?php echo get_the_date( '', 1 ); ?>
```